# save predictions from pytorch model

Tags: pytorch

Im following the pytorch transfer learning tutorial and applying it to the kaggle seed classification task,Im just not sure how to save the predictions in a csv file so that i can make the submission,
Any suggestion would be helpful,This is what i have ,

```
use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()
 model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(num_ftrs, len(classes))
if use_gpu:
    model = model.cuda()

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.fc.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

loaders = {'train':train_loader, 'valid':valid_loader, 'test': test_loader}

model = train_model(loaders, model, criterion, optimizer, exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=50)
```

Comment: can you give more info about output format?

Comment: Hmm,that s what im not too sure about

Comment: why do you want to save your data as a `csv` file? Just for readability? doing `torch.save` should be enough. If you want to be safe that there won't be unexpected gradients perhaps doing `tensor_data.detach().cpu().numpy()` then `torch.save` should be sufficient. For csv use `np.savetxt` on the numpy version of the data.

Answer (score 5):

Once you have trained your model, you can evaluate it on your testing data. This gives you a [Variable](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.0/autograd.html#variable), probably on the GPU. From there, you'll want to copy its [tensor](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.0/tensors.html) to the CPU with `cpu()` and convert it into a numpy array with `numpy()`. You can then use numpy's [CSV functionality](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) or use e.g. pandas' [DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). In the first case, you'd have something like this:

```
# evaluate on Variable x with testing data
y = model(x)
# access Variable's tensor, copy back to CPU, convert to numpy
arr = y.data.cpu().numpy()
# write CSV
np.savetxt('output.csv', arr)
```

Comment: when i run just `model.eval()` i get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'eval'`

Comment: Well, somehow you assigned a tuple to the `model` variable. Did you change anything from the tutorial? Besides, my answer doesn't even mention `model.eval()`.

Comment: Should i pass the test loader as variable x? im  a little confused what to do?

Comment: Usually it's good practice to save data from a NN using the `.detach()` e.g. `tensor_data.detach().cpu().numpy()` in that order. Detaching first avoids unnecessary copies of gradients.

Answer (score 2):

I am sharing the evaluation function which I used for SNLI task. Please note, this is just an example, not the exact answer, probably you are looking for. I hope it will help you!!

```
def evaluate(model, batches, dictionary, outfile=None):
    # Turn on evaluation mode which disables dropout.
    model.eval()

    n_correct, n_total = 0, 0
    y_preds, y_true, output = [], [], []
    for batch_no in range(len(batches)):
        sent1, sent_len1, sent2, sent_len2, labels = helper.batch_to_tensors(batches[batch_no], dictionary)
        if model.config.cuda:
            sent1 = sent1.cuda()
            sent2 = sent2.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()

        score = model(sent1, sent_len1, sent2, sent_len2)
        preds = torch.max(score, 1)[1]
        if outfile:
            predictions = preds.data.cpu().tolist()
            for i in range(len(batches[batch_no])):
                output.append([batches[batch_no][i].id, predictions[i]])
        else:
            y_preds.extend(preds.data.cpu().tolist())
            y_true.extend(labels.data.cpu().tolist())
            n_correct += (preds.view(labels.size()).data == labels.data).sum()
            n_total += len(batches[batch_no])

    if outfile:
        target_names = ['entailment', 'neutral', 'contradiction']
        with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
            f.write('pairID,gold_label' + '\n')
            for item in output:
                f.write(str(item[0]) + ',' + target_names[item[1]] + '\n')
    else:
        return 100. * n_correct / n_total, 100. * f1_score(numpy.asarray(y_true), numpy.asarray(y_preds),
                                                           average='weighted')
```

Usually, I call the eval function as follows:

```
evaluate(model, test_batches, dictionary, args.save_path + 'predictions.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to save the predictions as CSV. Is it for human readability?

Anyway, normally when converting to numpy we do:

```
tensor_data.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

in that order (to avoid duplicate compies of gradients we don't need).

Also, if you save the predictions and choose to save it as torch.tensor object then make sure you call `detach` to avoid unexpected gradients to be remembered (unless you want that I guess):

```
y = f(x)
torch.save({'y': y.detach().cpu()})
```

for saving it do CSV:

```
y = f(x).detach().cpu().numpy()
np.savetxt(path / `output.csv', y)
```

Though, I recommend you to just use print statements if its for debugging. Also, use `torch.save`, it does it all for you out of the box. I don't recommend pickle as that throws warning with pytorch.

---

For full working example:

```
# test for saving everything with torch.save

import torch
import torch.nn as nn

from pathlib import Path
from collections import OrderedDict

import numpy as np

import pickle

path = Path('~/data/tmp/').expanduser()
path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

num_samples = 3
Din, Dout = 1, 1
lb, ub = -1, 1

x = torch.torch.distributions.Uniform(low=lb, high=ub).sample((num_samples, Din))

f = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
    ('f1', nn.Linear(Din,Dout)),
    ('out', nn.SELU())
]))
y = f(x)

# save data torch to numpy
x_np, y_np = x.detach().cpu().numpy(), y.detach().cpu().numpy()
db2 = {'f': f, 'x': x_np, 'y': y_np}
torch.save(db2, path / 'db_f_x_y')
np.savetxt(path / 'output.csv', y_np)

db3 = torch.load(path / 'db_f_x_y')
f3 = db3['f']
x3 = db3['x']
y3 = db3['y']
xx = torch.tensor(x3)
yy3 = f3(xx)

print(yy3)
```